# Pandas GroupBy aggregation does not preserve dtypes

Tags: pandas

I use Pandas `GroupBy` and `Groupby.agg` by using functions such as `sum`, `max` and `min` for my numerical columns but I noticed that the data types I previously imposed to my columns (such as np.int8, np.int16, np.int32) are not preserved after the GroupBy aggregation and that actually every column is overcasted to int64.
Pandas version 1.1.5

My current solution is to just re-downcast once finished the groupby aggregation, is this a known issue and/or is there a nicer solution?

Comment: Could you give an example, please? On my side I keep the datatypes, but it's Pandas 1.2.3

Comment: Please provide your code. As shown, using the built-ins will preserve the dtype, but if for some reason you're using an unnecessary and inefficient lambda: `.groupby(...).apply(lambda x: x.sum())` then you get upcast to `int64`

Comment: Wait, do you assume he is using a lambda or did you get mixed up because I used one to show that types can get mixed using one?

Comment: I am digging into the issue - thanks for the quick feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tested on pandas version 1.1.5

I don't get the same result. Types are conserved.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,3,4,5], b=[1,2,3,4,5], c=[1,2,3,4,5]))
df = df.astype({'a': np.int8, 'b': np.int16, 'c': np.int32})
new_df = df.groupby(by='c').max()
print(new_df.dtypes)

""" Output - dtypes are conserved.
a     int8
b    int16
dtype: object
"""
```

Maybe you used an aggregator that went trough multiple columns. If you were to aggregate a + b => You'd get int16

```
new_df = df.groupby(by='c').apply(lambda x: x['a'] + x['b'])
print(new_df.dtypes)
# Output : int16
```

Comment: that is my case, I'm using an aggregator through multiple columns. For some of those, aggregation is 'mean' so I get floats always, but in other columns, my aggregation is 'sum', while the base columns are int64. Is there any way to prevent pandas from casting these to floats?