# groupby aggregation does not preserve dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Note the `.astype('int8')` in the following

```py
d = pd.DataFrame({c:np.random.choice(range(10),size=20) \
                  for c in list('abcd')}).astype('int8')
d.groupby(d.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size().info()
```

which yields

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 20 entries, 0 to 19
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   a       20 non-null     int64
 1   b       20 non-null     int64
 2   c       20 non-null     int64
 3   d       20 non-null     int64
 4   size    20 non-null     int64
dtypes: int64(5)
memory usage: 928.0 bytes
```

**Is there some way I can get pandas to preserve the original dtypes?** It uses too much memory otherwise.

My `pd.__version__` is `1.3.5`, and same result with `1.5.3` (but not `2.0.2` as @rickhg12hs comments!). According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66645100/1959887) the conversion should not occur, but that's inconsistent with what I observe.

Comment: With `pd.__version__` `==` `'2.0.2'` on my machine, each `Dtype` is `int8`, except the `size` row which is `int64`.

Comment: Use `.astype(np.int8)` instead?

Comment: I think this is something that got cleaned up. The issue is coming from your index - I tried converting it to int8 but it doesn't want to take: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.Int64Index.html

Comment: Tried tricking it with a multiindex too, that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want groupby here:

```
samp = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]],columns=['a','b','c'])
print(samp.groupby(samp.columns.to_list()).groups)
{(1, 2, 3): [0], (2, 3, 4): [1]}
```

You're creating a dataframe where the index is your values, which is only really useful if you're trying to count how many times each row occurs, in which case better options exist:

```
counts = np.unique(d.values, return_counts=True, axis=0)
ret = pd.DataFrame(counts[0], columns=d.columns)
ret['size'] = counts[1].astype('int8')
```

A `print(ret.dtypes)` will assure you we're entirely still in `int8`.